# Setting up AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, visualsvn-server

I have created a repository in a server using VisualSVN server.
I Installed AnkhSVN in my local machine and now i'm trying to 
add my local source to the repository.
I right clicked on the Soulution and clicked on Add "Solution to Subversion"
and the "Add to subversion " popup appear.
Once i typed in the Repository Url, it doesn't show the repository down below
and i cant add this to the repository.

The url is https://GP-WS16.gp.com.lk/svn/test

I tried with the port number as well https://GP-WS16.gp.com.lk:443/svn/test

I checked the server and the SVN server is running over there.

I have not installed TortoiseSVN or any other in my local machine other than AnkhSVN.
Do i need to?
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening View -> Repository Explorer. There use the + button to add a URL. This is just to confirm communication with the server.